# Create a new array of object from 2 other objects

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to create a new array of objects from data in 2 other objects(one of them is an array). 
First object i have is a simple key:value one which contains a record values.

```
const records = {
  title: 'My title',
  body: 'bla bla bla',
  created_at: 'some date'
};
```

The second is an array of object which holds field properties like the type and mandatory.

```
const fields = [
  {
    name: 'title',
    type: 'TextField',
    mandatory: true
  },
  {
    name: 'body',
    type: 'RichTextField',
    mandatory: false
  },
  {
    name: 'created_at',
    type: 'DateField',
    mandatory: true
  }
];
```

I am trying to search for every key on the first object and get the other properties in the second array. Basically I want something like this:

```
const newArray= [
  { name: title, value: 'My title', type: 'TextField', mandatory: true },
  { name: body, value: 'bla bla bla', type: 'RichTextField', mandatory: false },
  { name: created_at, value: 'some date', type: 'DateField', mandatory: true }
];
```

Comment: what does not work? please add your code.

Comment: Well i dont know how to start it. I am trying with .map and .reduce but no luck

Comment: Iterate over `fields`, check if `records` has a property that matches the value of `name` and store its content as `value` in the current "field" object

Comment: _"I am trying with .map and .reduce but no luck"_ - You've missed to show us the mentioned approaches.

Comment: `"I am trying with .map and .reduce but no luck"` - please add this code

Comment: btw, from where do you get `type`?

Comment: @NinaScholz from the second array

Comment: Something like this? `fields.map(f => ({ ...f, value: records[f.name] }) )`

Comment: map function would be probably the easiest to achieve what you want. One tip for you: to get value from the {key: value} object you can use this notation: `records["title"]` -> this will give you a "My title" value.

Answer (score 2):

You could map `fields` with the `value` from `records`.

```js
const
    records = { title: 'My title', body: 'bla bla bla', created_at: 'some date' },
    fields = [{ name: 'title', type: 'TextField', mandatory: true }, { name: 'body', type: 'RichTextField', mandatory: false }, { name: 'created_at', type: 'DateField', mandatory: true }];
    result = fields.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { value: records[o.name] }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using javascript methods. This is not just the only way. You can try other operators as well.

```js
const fields = [{ name: 'title', type: 'TextField', mandatory: true },
        { name: 'body', type: 'RichTextField', mandatory: false },
        { name: 'created_at', type: 'DateField', mandatory: true }
];

const records = {
  title: 'My title',
  body: 'bla bla bla',
  created_at: 'some date'
};
let newArray = [];
fields.forEach(field => {
  newArray.push({
    name: field.name,
    value: records[field.name],
    type: field.type,
    mandatory: field.mandatory
  })
})
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
  const fields = [{ name: 'title', type: 'TextField', mandatory: true },
  { name: 'body', type: 'RichTextField', mandatory: false },
  { name: 'created_at', type: 'DateField', mandatory: true }
];
const records = {
  title: 'My title',
  body: 'bla bla bla',
  created_at: 'some date'
};

let res = fields.map(val => {
  return { ...val,  value: records[val.name] }
})
console.log(res);
```